# SharePoint global navigation links duplicating

Tags: css, sharepoint, navigation, duplicates, settings

I'm really hoping someone can help. I have been researching this for a few days now and have got no where so have decided its time to ask.

My SharePoint site has many sub sites, all with pages and sub sites of their own. On the main homepage, the global navigation bar has a step down menu that links to sub sites.

My problem is recently, these have just started to duplicate themselves repeatedly until my menus are no longer usable (see screenshot)
[Duplicated Items screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXUfZ.jpg)

After researching I changed the global navigation settings to the "Structured navigation" option and selected only "Show Subsites" however this has not resolved the issue.

[Global Settings screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHGTE.jpg)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug with the publishing feature. The ultimate fix would be to install the hotfix or cumulative update that addresses the problem. A bug similar to this for SharePoint 2010 was addressed in the April 2013 CU.

As a workaround in the meantime... Since you know which of the global nav nodes is repeating itself, go find that node's underlying object (either a page or a subsite) and recycle it, either through the browser if possible, or through the powershell IDE on one of your SharePoint web servers. Deleting the object should get the publishing infrastructure to recognize that the object no longer exists and remove all of the duplicate links.

You can then restore the object from the site collection recycle bin.